# How to change listening interface of RabbitMQ's epmd (port 4369)

Tags: rabbitmq

In default, RabbitMQ's empd process listen on port 4369, and on interface/ip_addr.
How I can configure it to listen on a specific interface/ip_addr?
(I read documentation, and can configure beam.smp listen on a specific ip_addr, but not epmd)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The default epmd port is 4369, but this can be changed using the ERL_EPMD_PORT environment variable.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

see also:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html

Comment: He is asking for a change of the ip adress / inteface empd is listenign to. Not the port.

Answer (score 2):

Create `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` file and add: `export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1`

[more info](https://serverfault.com/questions/235669/how-do-i-make-rabbitmq-listen-only-to-localhost)