# RabbitMq Management plugin only on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, rabbitmq

On RabbitMQ 3.5.7 Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to implement RabbitMq Management plugin only on localhost, the idea is to use a tunnel to reach the RabbitMq Management Web GUI from the computer I use to connect to my server using SSH.

I found this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/235669/how-do-i-make-rabbitmq-listen-only-to-localhost) that seems to document everything to do.

Here is what I have done:
I edited /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf, it looks like that:

```
export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config"
# Defaults to rabbit. This can be useful if you want to run more than one node
# per machine - RABBITMQ_NODENAME should be unique per erlang-node-and-machine
# combination. See the clustering on a single machine guide for details:
# http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine
#NODENAME=rabbit

# By default RabbitMQ will bind to all interfaces, on IPv4 and IPv6 if
# available. Set this if you only want to bind to one network interface or#
# address family.
#NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1

# Defaults to 5672.
#NODE_PORT=5672

export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
export RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
```

Then I've created and edited "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config":

```
[
        {rabbitmq_management, [
                {listener,[{port, 15672},{ip, "127.0.0.1"}]}
        ]},
        {kernel, [
                {inet_dist_use_interface,{127.0.0.1}}
        ]}
].
```

I've launched some `service rabbitmq-server reload`, `service rabbitmq-server stop`, `service rabbitmq-server start`.

It did not work.

I rebooted the machine it is still not working.

When I do a `sudo lsof -i-n -P` I see that:

> beam    1199 rabbitmq    8u  IPv4  13374      0t0  TCP *:25672 (LISTEN)
>
> beam    1199 rabbitmq    9u  IPv4  13376      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:60223-127.0.0.1:4369 (ESTABLISHED)
>
> beam    1199 rabbitmq   18u  IPv4  14714      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5672 (LISTEN)
>
> beam    1199 rabbitmq   19u  IPv4  14716      0t0  TCP *:15672 (LISTEN)

In "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log", I can see:

> "config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config (not found)"

Comment: Which version of rabbitmq? Any info in the logs?

Comment: @MartinSchröder The RabbitMQ version is 3.5.7. What kind of log should I look for there? At first, it was giving me trouble to restart the service, because `export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/rabbitmq/rabbit.config"` was not located at the top of the config file and it was telling me to look for logs in  `journalctl -xe`, but once I moved that line at the top of `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` the service could reload and restart throwing no issue of any kind.

Comment: 3.5.7 is quite old, the latest is 3.6.9. Please try this. RabbitMQ has it's own log files, see the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, my mistake was:

`export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config"` instead of `export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq"` in  "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf"

It is not necessary to specify the extention ".config" of the file.

And in "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config", I just kept:

```
[
        {rabbitmq_management, [
                {listener,[{port, 15672},{ip, "127.0.0.1"}]}
        ]},
]
```

The node: `{kernel, [{inet_dist_use_interface,{127.0.0.1}}]}` was creating some conflict, I took it away with no further investigation.

Comment: I would just like to chime in that the last comma (line 4) in your example above kept my server from starting.