# Unable to stop RabbitMQ from listening on port 25672 on all interfaces

Tags: linux-networking, rabbitmq

I'm currently working on an application using celery in combination with rabbitmq, due to security concerns no services that don't require any connection with the internet should only listen on localhost.

After looking around I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/235669/how-do-i-make-rabbitmq-listen-only-to-localhost) question which shows how I can make *most* ports listen only on localhost, however for some reason port `25672` remains open, which I determined to be part of rabbitmq:

```
$ nmap -sV -p25672 -T5 <my server>

Starting Nmap 7.50 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-04 23:54 CEST
Nmap scan report for <my server> (<my server>)
Host is up (0.011s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE VERSION
25672/tcp open   unknown

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 124.87 seconds
```

On the server:

```
$ lsof -i :25672
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
beam.smp 4513 rabbitmq   12u  IPv4 473675236      0t0  TCP *:25672 (LISTEN)
```

The `man` entry for rabbitmq does not state how to change this, nor can I find out how to do so online. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to make it listen on `127.0.0.1` rather than `0.0.0.0`?

---

Edit: Fuck it, iptables will do.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 25672 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25672 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#dual-stack) in five seconds after searching for `rabbitmq port`...

> ```
> listeners.tcp.1 = 127.0.0.1:5672
> listeners.tcp.2 = ::1:5672
> ```
>
> Or in the classic config format:
>
> ```
> [
>   {rabbit, [
>     {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672},
>                      {"::1",       5672}]}
>   ]}
> ].
> ```

(Warning: You probably need both, as localhost resolves to ::1 on all OSes released in the last decade or so, and binding only to 127.0.0.1 could cause some apps to have problems.)

Comment: That simply does the same as [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/235669/how-do-i-make-rabbitmq-listen-only-to-localhost) question does, while this closed port `4369` for me, for whatever reason port `25672` won't seem to close when doing this

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, you can't run a cluster, then. That's the cluster communication port, and it must be open so that the other cluster nodes can communicate. Check your config and make sure you haven't got anything that might configure a cluster. You might also have to `rabbitmqctl reset`. If you intended to have a cluster, you'll need to configure a host firewall.